# "Guess the Number" in C

Tags: beginner, c, number-guessing-game

This is my first program in C. Do you have any improvements to this program? The program allows you to guess a number and also returns the attempts.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <time.h>
/*
 * Sophie
 * 21.03.2021
 */
void main() {
     int secret;
     int guess;
     int try = 1;

    time_t t;
    srand((unsigned ) time(&t));
    secret = rand() % 100+1;

    printf("Please Enter value:\n");
    scanf("%i", &guess);

    while (guess != secret){
        if (guess > secret)
            printf("Guess too high. \n");
        else
            printf("Guess too low. \n");

        printf("Please enter a new value:\n");
        scanf("%i", &guess);
        try++;
    }
    printf("You gussed the number! \n");
    printf("You needed %i Tries.", try);

    getch();
}
```

Comment: This is a great program to learn with!  The first program I ever wrote — in BASIC on a borrowed [Video Genie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Video_Genie), no less — was a guessing game.  Though after all this time I can't remember whether the computer picked the number and the human had to guess it (as here), or vice versa…  Both are good, so once you're happy with one, try the other!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I also liked the program - it did not compile, but that was easy to fix - what are `<conio>` and `getch()`?

I enjoyed a game or two, until I wondered if it was 0-99 or 1-100. The spacing of  `% 100+1` was a bit misleading.

I simplified the `time()` call.

Then I wondered why there are two `scanf()` calls. The input messages are different (please enter / please enter NEW), but the input itself is the same. So I ended up with `while(scanf() > 0)`.

It is not so clear what to put in that while condition. Also what to do with invalid input. My version stops and prints the number of tries.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
/* modified number guessing game, with while(scanf()) loop */
/* original by Sophie 21.03.2021 */

void main() {
    int secret, guess;
    int try = 0;
    srand(time(NULL));
    secret = rand() % 100 + 1;

    printf("Please enter first guess (1-100):\n");

    while (scanf("%i", &guess) > 0) {
        try++;
        if (guess == secret) {
            printf("You guessed the number!\n");
            break;
        }
        if (guess > secret)
            printf("Guess too high. ");
        else
            printf("Guess too low. ");

        printf("Please enter a new value:\n");
    }

    printf("You tried %i times.\n", try);
}
```

I am afraid you have to sacrifice that nice

```
while (guess != secret) {
```

and concentrate more on the scanf() *return*.

(Well with that negation `!=` it wasn't even that great - more like "trapped in eternal loop as long as guess is wrong")

Comment: *The spacing of  `% 100+1` was a bit misleading* don't fix that with spaces, use braces: `secret = (rand() % 100) + 1`;

Comment: @PaulEvans I'd call those brackets, round brackets, parentheses, or parens; braces are curly brackets — `{` and `}` — and have a very different meaning in most programming languages!  But yes, whatever you call them, they're useful for clarifying precedence.  This case is a bit subjective; I'd consider `%` similar enough to division that the precedence was already obvious — but if it's not obvious to you, by all means use brackets.

Comment: Your version still doesn't compile (error: invalid prototype for main function).

Comment: @gidds I should have looked it up and used *parentheses*, *round brackets*, or *first brackets* but I think the idea is clearly conveyed by the example. And don't *consider % similar enough to division that the precedence was already obvious* **use parentheses** to make your code **totally clear**! Be kind to your readers and to your future self, make reading your code as easy as possible.

Comment: @gidds "I'd consider % similar enough to division that the precedence was already obvious."   Obvious what the precedence is or obvious what precedence the previous coder intended?

Comment: The getch() at the end is used to implement "Press any key to continue", and that function is declared in conio.h (console I/O). It's a common Windows-ism because, if you launch a console program from the GUI, it will probably close the window when the program terminates, without giving you a chance to read the output.

Answer (score 15):

- `void main` is a really bad habit. It *must* be `int main`.
- Always check what `scanf` returns. For example, try to enter a non-numeric input, and see your program entering the infinite loop.
- Avoid `conio.h` (and hence `getch`). It is very non-portable.

Comment: It could be worth mentioning why is `void main` a bad habit. I don't think it's good to tell someone that something is bad, without telling why. (I believe the reason is because it is not valid C code, altho some compilers will ignore it and still compile it, but i might be wrong.)

Comment: Yes, the C standard mandates that main() returns an int. Moreover, the program needs to return a status code to the operating system, and this return value is how you do it. (Sometimes embedded systems don't have an operating system to return to, but usually they will either specify a different function to use or else they will still use int main() even though the return value is meaningless.)

Answer (score 3):

It looks good for a first program in C, good job.

An improvement would be to ask the user to insert a number which will be the maximum number to guess (instead of the default 100 value).

You also could change the `try` variable name to `tries`.

Comment: I think there are arguments both for `try` (which makes more sense within the loop) and `tries` (which reads better below it).  (I might pick `tries` myself, but probably from my experience in languages like Java and Kotlin where `try` is a keyword, which obviously doesn't apply here!)

Comment: That's right.

"attempts" could also be a great name for this variable.